# Get Image uint8 data without canvas

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas

I have a use case in which i want to pass image uint8 data to a web worker.
Right now i am using a canvas to do get the uint8 image data. Is there a way to do it without the canvas.

Here is the piece of code which i am using.

```
let img = new Image(),
        canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');

img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
img.src = someImageUrl;

img.onload = () => {
            canvas.height = this.naturalHeight;
            canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
            context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            const imgData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            // post this imgData to the worker
            worker.postMessage(imageData);
        };
```

Comment: The canvas dosn't provide **any** way to get a Uint8 representation of an image file. What it gets you is an Uint8ClampedArray containing RGBA channels of pixels corresponding to the ones in your image, but they are not the same, they've been computed and due to the lossy aspect of pre-multiplying induced by sRGB, there is just no way to get the exact values. (This is exploited in [canvas fingerprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_fingerprinting)) There are ways to get an Uint8 representation of your File though (with headers still compressed etc.). So which one of these do you want?

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for clarifying that, i want to get UInt8ClampedArray for my processing.

Answer (score 1):

In a near future, you should be able to go from an [ImageBitmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmap), that you would transfer to your Worker, where you would handle it in an [OffscreenCanvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas/OffscreenCanvas), which is not really an HTMLCanvas per se, but offers a way to access to the same contexts' methods, even inside a Worker.

As of today, only Chrome and Firefox has started the development of this API, and **they are still hidden under flags in both** ("*Experimental Web Platforms*" for Chrome and "*gfx.offscreencanvas.enabled*" for Firefox).
And even then, only Chrome has implemented the 2DContext there, for Firefox, you'd have to fallback to a webgl context, which I don't know much so I'll let the writing of a workaround using *readPixels* for someone else.

So yes, it will be possible to do it without an HTMLCanvasElement, but for now... I guess you'd be better to keep the canvas way.

```js
if (!window.ImageBitmap || !window.OffscreenCanvas) {
  console.log('Your browser doesn\'t support ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas, we should fallback to a normal canvas');
} else {
  var img = new Image();
  img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  img.onload = e => createImageBitmap(img).then(passToWorker);
  img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg";


  function passToWorker(bitmap) {
    var blob = new Blob([work.textContent], {
      type: 'application/javascript'
    });
    var worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
    worker.postMessage(bitmap, [bitmap]);
    worker.onmessage = e => {
      if (e.data instanceof ImageData) {
        console.log('ImageData', e.data.data.length, e.data.data[0]);
      } else {
        console.log(e.data);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

```html
<script id="work" type="worker-script">
onmessage = function(evt) {
  const bitmap = evt.data;
  try {
    const ctx = new OffscreenCanvas(bitmap.width, bitmap.height).getContext('2d');
    if(!ctx) fallbackToWebGL(bitmap);
    ctx.drawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
    handleImageData(ctx.getImageData(0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e, e.name);
    // FF doesn't even return null...
    if (e.name === 'NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED') {
     fallbackToWebGL(bitmap);
    }
    else postMessage('come back later');
  }
};

function handleImageData(data) {
  postMessage(data);
}

function fallbackToWebGL(bitmap) {
  postMessage('should fallback to webgl readPixels...');
}
</script>
```

---

Oh, and an other alternative would be to write yourself a parser of whatever format is your original image, and then extract the RGBA channels yourself, but honestly, using a Canvas is not that bad.

Comment: Thanks for such a clear answer. But it still doesnt seem to resolve the issue as the support the apis used is very limited.
Reason for using canvas is that, the images which i am fetching are from a different domain and it seems they have not implemented cors.

So when i do image.crossOrigin = "anonymous" it starts throwing cors error.
That team suggested us not to send image.crossOrigin and than we will be able to load image. When i remove image.crossOrigin my canvas starts throwing me error saying that it has become tainted.

Comment: @Anurag92 then why didn't you stated this in your question, or even simply asked how to circumvent this limitation? Now is too late though. And anyway, this question has already been answered many times and is a simple *"The only solution is to use a proxy server"*, so don't ask it again. [_EDIT_] You are in contact with the other hand? Explain to them that you must have the proper Allow-Origin headers, and if they are reluctant to set it to anyone, they may also set it only for your origin.