# Why is there no way to directly convert between data url and a imgData object?

Tags: javascript, todataurl

From what I've been able to find, the only way to get from imgURL to an imgData array is to create a canvas and draw an image onto that canvas. Why is there no direct way to convert between imgURL and an imgData array?

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716031/get-image-uint8-data-without-canvas

Comment: Why does it make a difference to you? What is the problem with that method, in other words?

Comment: @Pointy I'm having a bit of issues with asynchronous code in a script that needs to manipulate imgData arrays, but ideally should be able to take information in the format of ordinary images, such as jpegs.It simply struck me as strange that no libraries have been created for this purpose, and wanted to know if there is any particular reason why this should be impossible.